# Count rows of one column using functions and the data in the next column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns `col1` and `col2`. `col1` has letters (A and B), and `col2` has numbers (1 to 9). For the output I need `col1` with 2 letters, and some new columns:

- `total_numbers` - total numbers in each letter,
- `numbers_under_5` - number count under 5
- `lowest` - lowest value
- `highest` - highest value

Input:

```
|Col1|Col2|
|----|----|
|A   |1   |
|B   |1   |
|A   |2   |
|A   |7   |
|B   |6   |
```

Output:

```
|Col1|total_numbers|numbers_under_5|lowest|highest|
|----|-------------|---------------|------|-------|
|A   |3            |2              |1     |7      |
|B   |2            |1              |1     |6      |
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we need a custom function for `number less than 5` hence we had to split `groupby` into two dfs (df1 and df2) and then merged on `Col1` and finally renamed columns as per requirement.

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('Col1').Col2.apply(lambda x: x<5)].groupby('Col1').agg('last').reset_index()
df2 = df.groupby('Col1', as_index=False).Col2.agg(['count', 'min','max']).reset_index()
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Col1').rename(columns= {
    'Col2':'numbers_under_5',
    'count':'total_numbers',
    'min':'lowest',
    'max':'highest'
})
df
```

**Output**

```
Col1    numbers_under_5 total_numbers   lowest  highest
A       2               3               1       7
B       1               2               1       6
```

**PS** For `A` in `Col1` there are 2 values less than 5, since in the output you showed `2` hence I have taken the last value. You can use below code if you want `max value below 5` instead of `last value` for each group having more than one values less than 5.

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('Col1').Col2.apply(lambda x: x<5)].groupby('Col1').agg('max').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Col1').Col2.agg(['count', 'min','max', lambda x : len(x[x.astype(int) < 5])])
df1.columns = ['total_numbers', 'lowest' ,'highest' , 'numbers_under_5'] 
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```